# Installing Android SDK on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, android

I am trying to setup my Mac OS X for development purposes. I have successfully downloaded and setup the iPhone SDK. However, I also need to setup the Android SDK. Coming from a Windows background, there is an instruction that is confusing me. The instruction says:

*In the home directory locate the .bash_profile and locating the PATH variable add the location to your $SDK_ROOT/tools folder.*

From my interpretation, this looks like I'm supposed to add the Android Tools directory to my $PATH. However, I have no idea how to actually do this on Mac OS X. Can anybody please explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bash_profile` usually doesn't exist by default on OS X.  You need to edit it with your editor of choice to include:

```
PATH=$PATH:/<sdk_root>/tools
```

where `<sdk root>` is the path defined by $SDK_ROOT.

.bash_profile is, in essence, a shell script that gets run each time you start a new bash session (aka: create a new terminal window or tab, or type `bash` at any prompt). Accordingly, you can add any little snippets you wish to it, serious things such as environment variables, or goofy stuff like having it output funny ASCII art.